# mtdparts arguments seems ignored by linux kernel since Buster upgrade

Tags: debian, kernel, boot, u-boot, ubifs

Running Debian on my NAS for years. Vanilla Debian with linux-image-kirkwood/linux-image-kernel. Bootloader is u-boot.

With Debian Stretch (4.9.0-11-marvell) it was fine : u-boot handed the parameter `mtdparts=orion_nand:896k(u-boot),128k(u-boot-env),-(root)` to Linux, which used it to map the NAND and could happily mount the third partition on `/boot`, as ubifs.

Now that I upgraded to Buster (kernel 4.19.0-6-marvell), Linux seems to ignore the mtdparts parameter : it is passed fine :

```
# dmesg|grep mtdparts
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyS0,115200 ubi.mtd=2 mtdparts=orion_nand:896k(u-boot),128k(u-boot-env),-(root) root=/dev/sda rootflags=device=/dev/sda,device=/dev/sdb,defaults,noatime rootfstype=btrfs
```

… But seems ignored for some reason, in favor of some other layout (default ?) :

```
# cat /proc/mtd
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00100000 00020000 "u-boot"
mtd1: 00500000 00020000 "uImage"
mtd2: 00500000 00020000 "ramdisk"
mtd3: 06600000 00020000 "image"
mtd4: 00a00000 00020000 "mini firmware"
mtd5: 00500000 00020000 "config"
```

I did not upgraded u-boot.

Here is relevant information from u-boot side :

```
=> printenv 
autoload=no
baudrate=115200
boot_fdt=no
bootcmd=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} ${mtdparts} ${root_hdd} ; run load_ubifs ; bootm 0x1000000 0x1200000 0x0900000
bootdelay=3
bootenv=uEnv.txt
console=ttyS0,115200
ethact=egiga0
ethaddr=00:50:43:XX:XX:XX
filesize=8936df
importbootenv=echo Importing environment ...; env import -t ${loadaddr} ${filesize}
load_ubifs=ubi part root ; ubifsmount ubi:rootfs ; ubifsload 0x0900000 /kirkwood-dns325.dtb ; ubifsload 0x1000000 /uImage ; ubifsload 0x1200000 /uInitrd
loadaddr=0x800000
loadbootenv=fatload usb 0 ${loadaddr} ${bootenv}
mtddevname=u-boot
mtddevnum=0
mtdids=nand0=orion_nand
mtdparts=mtdparts=orion_nand:896k(u-boot),128k(u-boot-env),-(root)
nandloadimage=nand read ${loadaddr} kernel
nandroot=ubi0:rootfs ubi.mtd=rootfs
nandrootfstype=ubifs
optargs=ubi.mtd=2
partition=nand0,0
root_flash=ubi.mtd=root root=ubi0:rootfs rootfstype=ubifs
root_hdd=root=/dev/sda rootflags=device=/dev/sda,device=/dev/sdb,defaults,noatime rootfstype=btrfs
setbootargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} ${mtdparts} root=${bootenvroot} rootfstype=${bootenvrootfstype}
setnandbootenv=echo Booting from nand ...; setenv bootenvroot ${nandroot}; setenv bootenvrootfstype ${nandrootfstype}; setenv bootenvloadimage ${nandloadimage}
stderr=serial
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
subbootcmd=run setbootargs; if run bootenvloadimage; then bootm ${loadaddr};fi;
```

```
=> mtdparts

device nand0 <orion_nand>, # parts = 3
 #: name                size            offset          mask_flags
 0: u-boot              0x000e0000      0x00000000      0
 1: u-boot-env          0x00020000      0x000e0000      0
 2: root                0x07f00000      0x00100000      0

active partition: nand0,0 - (u-boot) 0x000e0000 @ 0x00000000

defaults:
mtdids  : nand0=orion_nand
mtdparts: mtdparts=orion_nand:896k(u-boot),128k(u-boot-env),5m(kernel),-(rootfs)
```

```
=> version

U-Boot 2014.01 (Jan 21 2014 - 18:35:47)
D-Link DNS-325
arm-none-eabi-gcc (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.05-23) 4.7.3
GNU ld (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.05-23) 2.23.52.20130219
```

While booting, right before handing off to linux :

```
UBI: available PEBs:             0
UBI: total number of reserved PEBs: 1012
UBI: number of PEBs reserved for bad PEB handling: 10
UBI: max/mean erase counter: 13/7
UBIFS: mounted UBI device 0, volume 0, name "rootfs"
UBIFS: mounted read-only
UBIFS: file system size:   127346688 bytes (124362 KiB, 121 MiB, 987 LEBs)
UBIFS: journal size:       9033728 bytes (8822 KiB, 8 MiB, 71 LEBs)
UBIFS: media format:       w4/r0 (latest is w4/r0)
UBIFS: default compressor: zlib
UBIFS: reserved for root:  0 bytes (0 KiB)
Loading file '/kirkwood-dns325.dtb' to addr 0x00900000 with size 12863 (0x0000323f)...
Done
Loading file '/uImage' to addr 0x01000000 with size 2045912 (0x001f37d8)...
Done
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution. There is a related bug in latest debian: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=931852

The `mtdparts` option had became `cmdlinepart.mtdparts` (in Debian-land, at least).

Thus running the following at u-boot prompt made it OK :

```
setenv bootcmd 'setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} cmdlinepart.${mtdparts} ${root_hdd} ; run load_ubifs ; bootm 0x1000000 0x1200000 0x0900000'
saveenv
boot
```